# How to make sure two different primary replica deploy on different node in Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a 4 node service fabric cluster. I have created a stateful service with the following parameter

```
<Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="app_PartitionCount" Value="3" />
    <Parameter Name="app_MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
    <Parameter Name="app_TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
  </Parameters>
```

After deploying to Service Fabric cluster, two partitioon's primary replica of a stateful service reside on the same node.how to make sure every primary replica deployed on different node in a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

From a technical perspective, there is a number of ways you could try:

**Preferred domain** - specifies the fault domain to place the Primary in. The Primary ends up in this domain when everything is healthy. If the domain or the Primary replica fails or shuts down, the Primary moves to some other location, ideally in the same domain.

```
New-ServiceFabricService -ApplicationName $applicationName -ServiceName $serviceName -ServiceTypeName $serviceTypeName –Stateful -MinReplicaSetSize 3 -TargetReplicaSetSize 3 -PartitionSchemeSingleton -PlacementPolicy @("PreferredPrimaryDomain,fd:/0")
```

**Placement constraints** -  are the statements attached to individual services that select for one or more node properties. Placement constraints define where services should run. The set of constraints is extensible - any key/value pair can work.

```
New-ServiceFabricService -ApplicationName $applicationName -ServiceName $serviceName -ServiceTypeName $serviceType -PlacementConstraint "NodeName == $nodename" -Stateful -PartitionSchemeUniformInt64 -PartitionCount 3 -LowKey 0 -HighKey 51 -MinReplicaSetSize 3 -TargetReplicaSetSize 3
```

**Balancing Thresholds** - each primary instance could report some 'auxiliary' metric, like 'PrimaryCnt'. Having this in place, you could set up a threshold to ask/advise SF to preserve the desired ratio of this metric on a given node.

P.S.

Even though there are ways to do this, the default configuration is a smart one so make sure you'll get some benefits in the end if you do this your way.